# Get JSON Data from Array Within an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to figure out how I can get data from a JSON array that is in another array.

Here is the JSON. I'm wanting to get one of the image URLs from photos.

```
[

    {
        "id":6901439,
        "name":"INDTTIN CD",
        "description":"Full-length released June 2013 via Little Heart Records. \r\n\r\nTrack Listing:\r\n\r\n1. Tired\r\n2. Time to Heal\r\n3. Gypsy Summer\r\n4. Sketchbooks\r\n5. I Never Deserve the Things I Need\r\n6. Say it With the \"I\"\r\n7. A Negative Mind\r\n8. Rafters\r\n9. Indrid Cold\r\n10. Present Tense ",
        "short_url":"http://onmyhonor.storenvy.com/products/6901439-indttin-cd",
        "status":"active",
        "labels":null,
        "preorder":false,
        "on_sale":true,
        "store_id":373949,
        "price":"7.00",
        "marketplace_category":"music-cds",
        "marketplace_category_id":345,
        "photos":[
            {
                "photo":{
                    "original":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_original.jpg",
                    "large":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_large.jpg",
                    "homepage":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_homepage.jpg",
                    "medium":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_medium.jpg",
                    "small":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_small.jpg",
                    "64w":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_64w.jpg",
                    "200w":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_200w.jpg",
                    "400w":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_400w.jpg",
                    "600w":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_600w.jpg",
                    "1000w":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_1000w.jpg",
                    "64sq":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_64sq.jpg",
                    "200sq":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_200sq.jpg",
                    "400sq":"//d111vui60acwyt.cloudfront.net/product_photos/15878486/inddthin_20vinyl_20image_201_400sq.jpg"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variants":[
            {
                "variant":{
                    "id":14382188,
                    "name":"INDTTIN CD",
                    "position":1,
                    "sku":"",
                    "full_quantity":300,
                    "in_stock":300,
                    "percent_available":100,
                    "is_default_variant?":false,
                    "price":7.0,
                    "sold_out":false,
                    "status":"active"
                }
            }
        ],
        "collections":[
        ],
        "store":{
            "id":373949,
            "name":"On My Honor",
            "marketplace_url":"http://www.storenvy.com/stores/373949-on-my-honor"
        }
    }

]
```

Here is my code:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define storeURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://onmyhonor.storenvy.com/products.json"]

#import "GRSStoreViewController.h"
#import "GRSStoreDetailViewController.h"

@interface GRSStoreViewController ()

@end

@implementation GRSStoreViewController
@synthesize name, description, short_url, price, productImage, nameArray, descriptionArray, urlArray, priceArray, imageArray, url;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Store";

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://onmyhonor.storenvy.com/products.json"];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    priceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for (NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        description = [item objectForKey:@"description"];
        short_url = [item objectForKey:@"short_url"];
        price = [item objectForKey:@"price"];
        [nameArray addObject:name];
        [descriptionArray addObject:description];
        [urlArray addObject:short_url];
        [priceArray addObject:price];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [nameArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    if (cell)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GRSStoreDetailViewController *itemDetail = [[GRSStoreDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GRSStoreDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    itemDetail.priceString = [priceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    itemDetail.descriptionString = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    itemDetail.itemURL = [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemDetail animated:YES];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You should format JSON before posting.

Comment: and json data is wrong.... and for photos,, i think you need to write code like, yourarray = [json valueForKey:@"Photoes"];   i am not sure about it because i cant understand your json data..

Comment: With the formatted JSON the structure is quite obvious (if you understand JSON syntax which you can quickly learn at json.org).  You have an outer array, then an object.  Inside the object is a key/value pair named "photos" where the value is an array.  Entries in that array are objects where one of the keys is "photo" and its value is another object containing key/value pairs for the various URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change loop to

```
for (NSDictionary *item in json)
{
    NSArray *photos = item[@"photos"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [photos[0] valueForKeyPath:"photo"];
    NSLog(@"original = %@", dict[@"original"]);


    name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
    description = [item objectForKey:@"description"];
    short_url = [item objectForKey:@"short_url"];
    price = [item objectForKey:@"price"];
    [nameArray addObject:name];
    [descriptionArray addObject:description];
    [urlArray addObject:short_url];
    [priceArray addObject:price];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for (NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        description = [item objectForKey:@"description"];
        short_url = [item objectForKey:@"short_url"];
        price = [item objectForKey:@"price"];
        [nameArray addObject:name];
        [descriptionArray addObject:description];
        [urlArray addObject:short_url];
        [priceArray addObject:price];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

To this

```
NSdictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

  name = [json objectForKey:@"name"];
  description = [json objectForKey:@"description"];
  short_url = [json objectForKey:@"short_url"];
  price = [json objectForKey:@"price"];

  // this is your photos array
  NSArray *photos = [josn objectForKey:@"photos"];
  // every object in this array is a dictionary. In your case this array has only one dictionary so
  NSDictionary *photosDict = [photos firstObject];
  // from here you can access all keys of photosDict
```

All available keys in your photosDict:

- original
- large
- homepage
- medium
- small
- 64w
- 200w
- 400w
- 600w
- 1000w
- 64sq
- 200sq
- 400sq